# "Kim wants John to stop" -- does a VP in this example contain another VP?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I'm trying to draw the syntax tree for the TP "Kim wants John to stop" (in the setting of Carnie's first three chapters).

I guess it contains the NP "Kim" and the VP "wants John to stop". The VP consists of the V "wants", NP "John", and [something else] "to stop".

What is that [something else]? This piece "to stop" cannot be a PP because the only rule for PP is PP -> P (NP) and "stop" is not a NP, it's a VP (or am I wrong)? And the fact that "to stop" is a VP contained inside another VP ("wants John to stop") ruins the whole theory because there cannot be a VP inside a VP. Am I wrong in saying that "wants John to stop" is a VP then? If so, what is it?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything to prevent a VP from containing a VP. Is this part of the theory covered in the textbook?

Comment: Consider a sentence like "I told you that I wanted Bob to start considering proposing a committee to discuss implementing the changes."  Looking at the output of an automated parser like http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp might also be informative.

Comment: @Jetpack The rule for VP in Carnie (3rd edition) is VP -> (AdjP+) V (NP) ({NP/CP}) (AdvP+) (PP+) (AdvP+). So a VP cannot contain another VP.